# change div if date month equals input hidden value

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, if-statement

I am attempting to write some dynamic javascript code that changes background color of divs depending on the month we are in. For an example if we are in todays month the 4 ie April then change the div that contains the hidden value of the 4.

The code below does change the background of a div but I have to manually change the name of the divs for this to work. I would like this to take place automatically. I am looking for guidance. If anyone can help thanks.

So far I have written this code.

```
<style type="   ">
#content{
width: auto;
height:250px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#33F;
background: #FFF;
}
</style>

<script>
function change(){
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();
var e = document.getElementById("april").value;

if (n = e)
    {
        document.getElementById("content4").style.background = "red";
        document.getElementById("content4").style.height = "250px";

    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="change()">
<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="january" value="0" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="february" value="1" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="march" value="2" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content4">
<input hidden type="text" id="april" value="3" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="may" value="4" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="june" value="5" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="july" value="6" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="august" value="7" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="september" value="8" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div><div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="october" value="9" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="november" value="10" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div><div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="december" value="11" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="may" value="6" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div><div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="may" value="5" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="may" value="6" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div><div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="may" value="5" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<input hidden type="text" id="may" value="6" />
<h2></h2>
<p>News letter addition one</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use PHP for this?

Comment: you cannot use the same id 12 times :), but class yes

Comment: I am not able to use php for this. I would be able to assign the values to an array and loop through it until it matches the month number? Thats my logic on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function change() {
   var month = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', ...];
   var d = new Date();
   var n = d.getMonth();
   var currentMonth = month[n];
   var hiddenInput = document.getElementById(currentMonth);
   var div = hiddenInput.parentNode;
   div.style.background = "red";
   div.style.height = "250px";
}

// to get the months-names:
var hiddens = document.querySelectorAll('input[hidden]');
var month = Array.prototype.map.call(hiddens, function (a) { return a.id; });
```

Comment: I was thinking of using arrays. This solution does works highlighting the forth div box. Do I still need the hidden input boxes still? I understand most of the code apart from this bit _var div = hiddenInput.parentNode;_

Comment: this is a good method it seems slightly over complicated. Saying that I was curious to know this method as I was thinking the same thing. So thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code and html and just use a switch statement.  You would need 12 separate if statement to handle each div.  The below checks the month, and based on that adds the red background.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .content
        {
            width: auto;
            height: 250px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #33F;
            background: #FFF;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="change()">
    <div class="content" id="jan">
        <h2>January</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="feb">
        <h2>February</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="mar">
        <h2>March</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="apr">
        <h2>April</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="may">
        <h2>May</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="jun">
        <h2>June</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="jul">
        <h2>July</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="aug">
        <h2>August</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="sep">
        <h2>September</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="oct">
        <h2>October</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="nov">
        <h2>November</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="dec">
        <h2>December</h2>
        <p>News letter addition one</p>
    </div>

    <script>

        function change()
        {
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getMonth();
            switch (n)
            {
                case 0: document.getElementById("jan").style.background = "red";
                    break;
                case 1: document.getElementById("feb").style.background = "red";
                    break;
                case 2: document.getElementById("mar").style.background = "red";
                    break;
                case 3: document.getElementById("apr").style.background = "red";
                    break;
                case 4: document.getElementById("may").style.background = "red";
                    break;
                case 5: document.getElementById("jun").style.background = "red";
                    break;
                case 6: document.getElementById("jul").style.background = "red";
                    break;
                case 7: document.getElementById("aug").style.background = "red";
                    break;
                case 8: document.getElementById("sep").style.background = "red";
                    break;
                case 9: document.getElementById("oct").style.background = "red";
                    break;
                case 10: document.getElementById("nov").style.background = "red";
                    break;
                case 11: document.getElementById("dec").style.background = "red";
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate this @BrettL however simple the code its not that developer friendly as I would have to copy different styles in multiple times. But I do like how you've used the case statement for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are other better ways to acheive this,this should be done on server side. but just in this case
You can try creating a css for different months and change the class via javascript :

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();        
document.getElementById("content").className = n;
```

Add all months in CSS (just for a hint):

```
 .april{
          color: red;    

        }
```